# PDF to Image convertor

Tags: pdf

I'm taking recommendations for either a library in Python or Ruby or a free web service that will simply take a PDF and a pair of image dimensions and spit out an image for each page (jpg or png).  Nothing complicated! But it must have point-for-point accuracy to the original PDF.  That is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick uses Ghostscript for PDF files. So skip ImageMagick and use Ghostscript directly. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GIMP. Its a very good interface.

1. Import the pdf file to GIMP
2. Save the file as .xcf
3. Operate on the image - edit if required
4. Export in whatever format you want: .bmp, .jpeg, .png etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :) ([ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)).