# android how to convert pdf to image and load in imageview

Tags: android, pdf, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I'm developing an android application get the PDFs from j son and convert the PDFs files into image and display converted images on a image view. (not a web view or PDFs viewer)

i need to convert the PDFs to images and load that images on a imageview. is that possible??
and how can i achieve this task.
i have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java/16294833#16294833) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245429/pdf-page-convert-into-image).

appreciate any help ..

Comment: Just tested, and this answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27536939/1048340

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes i also used some kind of a same kind of a way to overcome the problem.

Comment: You should post and accept your own answer. Glad I came across this because it helped me in my own project :)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently worked in the same context ,PDFViewer via native solution (ndk) , the best solution which i have found it is mupdf library is under GPL licence .
You can inspire your solution from this project : https://github.com/smartmobilefactory/PDFViewer-Android

You need compile the native library of mupdf and then compile the project .

Get some idea how to compile it : http://mupdf.blogspot.com/

Good luck